# RS-232 signal level inversion

Tags: rs232, logic-level

Bit of a noob question but i'm having trouble understanding rs-232.

I'm sending data out over serial on an Atmel XMEGAA1U chip located on an Atmel XMEGA Xplained pro broad.

If i send binary 0000 0001, what is received at the other end (seen through a protocol analyzer) is 1111 1110.

From what i understand (google) this is normal as rs-232 inverts the logic.

What i don't know is whether I have to accommodate this inversion and flip the logic so the receiving end can just read it raw or if its normally the job of the receiving party to do the inversion.

What the "Standard" case of sending rs-232?

My requirements are just to send data over rs-232 with no mention of doing any logic conversion.

Thanks

Comment: We probably need a schematic to assist you with this. Are you using RS232 driver chips such as the MAX232?

Comment: That's not normal. Are you really sending it out over RS485 and got A&B mixed up at the receive end?

Comment: We need to know if you're using ACTUAL RS-232 (inverted logic levels, +/-12V), or "TTL level RS232" (0 and 5V, no inversion) or a different convention at each end (which sounds likely).

Comment: @BrianDrummond 's comment matters. RS-232 voltage levels are +3 to +15 V for a *SPACE* symbol and -3 to -15 V for a *MARK* symbol. A *MARK* is taken as a "1" by a proper RS-232 receiver circuit and a *SPACE* is taken as a "0". However, if you just wire up a proper RS-232's transmitter output directly to a micro's input pin (gosh help the protection diodes there), then your I/O pin will "see" a *MARK* as a "0" and a *SPACE* as a "1". You are talking about the other direction and it appears the analyzer handles out-of-band signalling giving you bits. But you are signaling incorrectly for RS-232.

Comment: Microcontroller UARTS generally have a setting to invert the signal if desired, so you wouldn't have to do any inversion in hardware anyway.

Comment: To receive the data correctly you need either inversion at both ends or at neither. In addition there are some micros that can optionally provide inversion on the UART, but it is not that common.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The normal configuration for an RS-232 link between two pieces of equipment is this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fQB1iJ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

As shown above as well as changing the voltage levels the line drivers (typically a MAX232 or some similar part) also invert the signals. As long as you use line drivers at both ends of the link (or skip them completely and run the link at logic levels) then you don't need to worry about the signal inversion.

There are also some cheap hacks of RS-232 drivers used for hobbyist systems which invert the signal but don't give the voltage levels required by the RS-232 specification and so you may sometimes see signal levels of 0 to 5 V rather than the -3V to +3V minimum range required by the RS-232 specification. While technically a violation of the specification these will normally work fine at lower speeds.

Hopefully this also explains why you need to be careful not to connect the TTL level serial interface you get out of most processors directly to an RS-232 port. Not only will the signal be inverted and so not work as a data link, few processors can take -15V on their IO pins without going pop.

Comment: Using the RS-232 protocol at logic levels may not comply with the standard, but it is not a 'cheap hack' nor is it only used in hobbyist equipment. It is a common method of communication between boards in industrial equipment and such.

Comment: @JeannePindar Using UARTs at TTL levels is fine. As is using your own propitiatory line driving system within a closed system (just don't call it RS-232 if you do that). I was referring to using a couple of transistors to invert and clamp voltages so that a device pretends to be using true RS232 levels and claims to be RS232 compatible but isn't.

Comment: Oh, you mean using some transistors instead of an rs-232 transceiver IC?  Yeah, there's no reason to do that.

Comment: Many thanks for this. The problem is wider than i first thought. At first i thought it was logic inversion but this just so happened to work in the one case. I can't make any sense of the output. I output "J" from my micro-controller and get hex AD on the analyzer??. The example i'm using was taken straight from the ATMEL example solution provided in the IDE. This was however outputing to the internal terminal debug port and does indeed output "J". So i'm guesting there something i'm not doing correctly in the setup. will investigate MAX232, thanks

Comment: Indeed the Atmel XMEGAA1U chip and the Atmel XMEGA Xplained pro broad to NOT have RS-232 modules fitted to them.Once i used this cable all was well with the world: http://uk.farnell.com/ftdi/ttl-232r-3v3/cable-usb-to-ttl-level-serial/dp/1329311